# Content Fetching Using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let I have two domains named **www.abc.example** and **www.xyz.example** hosted in **different servers**.

I have a **.htaccess** file in the **root directory** of *www.abc.example* (i.e. *www.abc.example/.htaccess*)

What will be the .htaccess **script** if I want to load the contents of *www.xyz.example* when I request from *www.abc.example*.

As for example:
If I browse **www.abc.example/test** then it will display the content of **www.xyz.example/test** and so on without changing the **host url** (i.e. *www.abc.example*) in browser's **addressbar**.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is run a reverse proxy. It requires [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on the server.

The documentation [seems to suggest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples) you'd want something like:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://www.xyz.example/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.xyz.example/
```

Assuming that such configuration is allowed in `.htaccess`. If not, you will have to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and a RewriteRule with the `[P]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.xyz.example/$1 [P]
```

If you're going the RewriteRule route, don't forget to add `RewriteEngine On` if it isn't there already!